# Why does this produce a stretched Fractal?

Tags: math, fractals

Here is pseudo-code of how I setup an array representing the MandelBrot set, yet it becomes horribly stretched when leaving an aspect ratio of 1:1.

```
xStep = (maxX - minX) / width;
yStep = (maxY - minY) / height;

for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
 for(j = 0; j < height; j++)
  {
   constantReal = minReal + xStep * i;
   constantImag = minImag + yStep * j;
   image[i][j] = inSet(constantReal, constantImag);
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what the function 'inSet' is doing.

Comment: It calculates how many iterations away that point is, returning the number of iterations or 0 if it's "too far" away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here is pseudo-code of how I setup an array representing the MandelBrot set, yet it
>   becomes horribly stretched when leaving an aspect ratio of 1:1.

```
xStep = (maxX - minX) / width;
yStep = (maxY - minY) / height;
```

Aha! It's because you must keep the same aspect ratio *both* for the image you will draw *and* for the region of the complex plane you want to draw. In other words, it must hold

```
 width     maxX - minX
---------- = ---------------------
 height    maxY - minY
```

(It follows that xStep == yStep.) Your code probably does not enforce this requirement.

Comment: That's it! That never occurred to me. Thanks a ton man. 2:1 works when I have a 2:1 in display-space and complex-space.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with how you are displaying the `image` array.  You use the width variable i as the first index, but usually the first index should be the slowest changing, that is, the height.

Try changing the last line to `image[j][i] =` ...

Comment: Wouldn't that flip it horizontally and vertically, rather than stretching it out?

Comment: Worse yet, it would write to memory outside of the array if width were not equal to height, which is what the OP is trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your casts are all correct.  xStep and yStep might be the products of integer division instead of the expected floating point division (if that's C# in your sample, it would require some explicit casts to work correctly).